# Binding to Xceed Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to bind to the graph control in Xceed (Wpf toolkit extended plus).

However, [the documentation](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/#Chart%20control.html)  has left me more confused...

It says

> The data points of a series can be set directly using the DataPoints property, but they can also be set by binding the DataPointsSource property of the Series class to a source and then populating DataPointBindings with BindingInfo objects, which store binding information for a single property of the DataPoint class. Use the BindingInfo.Binding property to set the Binding object for a given DataPoint property (i.e., Content, Label, X, or Y) and use the BindingInfo.PropertyName property (whose type is DataPointPropertyName) to set the property to use binding for.

So, my XAML is

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
  <loc:BackupResultsViewModel x:Key="MyVm" />
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusCollection" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyVm}, Path=MyData}" />
</StackPanel.Resources>

<xctk:Chart Height="30" Width="300" ShowLegend="True" >
  <xctk:Chart.Legend>
    <xctk:Legend Dock="Left" AllowResize="False" AllowDock="True" AllowMove="True" Title="Legend"/>
  </xctk:Chart.Legend>

  <xctk:Chart.Areas>
    <xctk:Area Title="Overall status" >
      <xctk:Area.XAxis>
        <xctk:Axis ShowAxisLabel="False" ShowTickLabels="False" ShowTicks="False"/>
      </xctk:Area.XAxis>

      <xctk:Area.YAxis>
        <xctk:Axis  ShowAxisLabel="False" ShowTickLabels="False" ShowTicks="False"/>
      </xctk:Area.YAxis>

      <xctk:Area.Series>
        <xctk:Series Title="Overall status" DataPointsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusCollection}}">
          <xctk:Series.Layout>
            <xctk:PieLayout />
          </xctk:Series.Layout>

          <xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>
            <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Y">
              <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                <Binding/>
              </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
            </xctk:BindingInfo>

            <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="X">
              <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                <Binding/>
              </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
            </xctk:BindingInfo>

            <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Label">
              <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                <Binding/>
              </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
            </xctk:BindingInfo>
          </xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>

        </xctk:Series>
      </xctk:Area.Series>
    </xctk:Area>
  </xctk:Chart.Areas>
</xctk:Chart>
```

and my code behind is

```
public GraphViewModel()
{
  this.Title = title;

  var data = new DataPointsList<DataPoint>();
  data.Add(new DataPoint(0, 8, "0"));
  data.Add(new DataPoint(1, 4, "1"));
  data.Add(new DataPoint(2, 3, "2"));
  data.Add(new DataPoint(3, 2, "3"));

  this.MyData = data;        
}

public DataPointsList<DataPoint> MyData { get; set; }
```

The graph shows, but, never with any data.

So, how can I get binding to work with my graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it

```
  <!-- ... -->

  <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Y">
    <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
      <Binding Path="Y"/> <!--NOTE-->
    </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
  </xctk:BindingInfo>

  <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="X">
    <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
      <Binding Path="X"/><!--NOTE-->
    </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
  </xctk:BindingInfo>

  <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Label">
    <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
      <Binding Path="Label"/><!--NOTE-->
    </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
  </xctk:BindingInfo>
</xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>
```